# Unreal Engine 4 create custom input device plugin

Tags: c++, plugins, unreal-engine4

I want create a custom plugin for Unreal Engine 4.

I have downloaded Unreal Engine 4.13 source code and I have followed this guide with success:
https://wiki.unrealengine.com/Custom_input_device_plugin_guide

I have compiled UE4 editor and running it I can see my plugin works fine.

Now I want to share my plugin with other people so I have copied my plugin folder (with all binaries) on the plugin folder (Engine\Plugins\Developer) on another PC where Unreal Engine 4.13 was installed using Epics Game launcher (so in this PC I don't have the source code of Unreal Engine but the release version installed on C:\Program Files x86....."

The problem is that when I launch some project I see the error message:

"MyPlugin.dll missing or build with a different engine version" and suggest me to build. I choose ok and clicking on "show log" I can read "Target is up to date". Then this window shutdown and I receive the error message that ask me to rebuild my plugin manually.

What's wrong?

Thanks in advance for any suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to put the plugin in your game project and let it compile?
I downloadd a plugin without Binaries, and got the same problem if I put it in `Engine/Plugins`, but it compiles fine in `MyGameProject/Plugins`.

Comment: Yes, I have tried and works fine if is a "basic plugin".

In my case an InputDevice plugin require some additional include that are not loaded from the project.

I have solve my problem added all additional include required but is quite boring works.

Comment: @DaxDeveloper Great that it worked. But I'd like to make sure, did you end up put the plugins in `Engine/Plugins` or `MyPorject/Plugins`?

Comment: Works on MyProject/Plugin. At the specific case is necessary add the following put to the project in order to solve any compile stuff related to IInputDevice:  YourEngineDir\Source\Runtime\Core\Public\GenericPlatform;C:\Program Files (x86)\Epic Games\4.13\Engine\Source\Runtime\InputDevice\Private

Comment: Ah if you need any headers in private section then it's a headache. Well I'm not sure about the correct way to use private headers, but as I read the engine source code I think it's better to use relative path instead of absolute path. Like "../../../Engine/Source/Runtime/InputDevice/Private", this is used in many places in the engine source codes, you can search for "/Private".